# How to document an inherited constructor using Yard

Tags: ruby, yard

Having classes, such as:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(data)
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
end
```

Each subclass that inherits from `Foo` has its own unique attributes, passed in via the `data` options hash.

The yard output for `Bar` states:

```
Constructor Details
This class inherits a constructor from Foo
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to document the options for `Bar#initialize`.

Attempts include:

```
class Bar < Foo
  # @overload initialize(data)
  #   @param data [Hash]
  #   @option data [String] :baz Value for baz attribute
end
```

(does nothing)

```
class Bar < Foo
  # @param data [Hash]
  # @option data [String] :baz Value for baz attribute
  # @!parse def initialize(data); end
end
```

(creates an undocumented constructor with "view source" showing the fake method)

```
class Bar < Foo
  # @!parse
  #   @param data [Hash]
  #   @option data [String] :baz Baz attr
  #   def initialize(data); end
end
```

(does nothing, result is the same as with `@overload` above)

How can I document the options for the subclasses using YARD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this with yard. And ruby version 2.6

```
class Foo
  def initialize(data)
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  # @overload initialize(data)
  # @param [String] data list
  # def initialize()
  # end
end
```

And check the generated `class_list.html` file.

Tested it on a Linux distro.

---

If there's any other technical issue, or you need a customized Ruby documentation solution as a temporary measure.